# como agregar datos nulos a un diccionario?

Tags: c#, postgresql

estoy realizando una consulta en postgresql, Trabajando con diccionario de datos en c#, pero me marca un error al agregarlos mandando este mensaje "Object cannot be cast from DBNull to other types". Debido a quela vista donde quiero estraer los datos contiene nulos,La tabla de pg_stat_activity..he intentando poner condiciones pero no funciona. Alguien me podria ayudar..gracias
Codigo:

```
conex.Open();
NpgsqlCommand coman = new NpgsqlCommand("SELECT pid,usename,application_name,datname,client_addr,backend_start,state,query_start,xact_start,wait_event,query FROM pg_stat_activity ORDER BY query_start DESC", conex);
                NpgsqlDataReader dat = coman.ExecuteReader();
                while (dat.Read())
                {
                    Entidades obj = new Entidades();
                    if (obj == null || obj !=null)

                    {                        
                    obj.pid = Convert.ToInt32(dat["pid"]);
                        obj.usename = Convert.ToString(dat["usename"]);
                        obj.appcationName = Convert.ToString(dat["application_name"]);
                        obj.datname = Convert.ToString(dat["datname"]);
                        obj.client_ddr = Convert.ToString(dat["client_addr"]);
                        obj.backed_star = Convert.ToDateTime(dat["backend_start"]);
                        obj.state = Convert.ToString(dat["state"]);
                        obj.query_star = Convert.ToDateTime(dat["query_start"]);
                        obj.Xact_star = Convert.ToDateTime(dat["xact_start"]);
                        obj.waiting = Convert.ToString(dat["wait_event"]);
                        obj.query = Convert.ToString(dat["query"]);
                        dic.Add(obj.pid, obj);
if (!dic.ContainsKey(obj.pid))//si el dic no contieene el id agregar
                            {
                                dic.Add(obj.pid, obj);

                            }
                            else
                            {
                                dic[obj.pid].query_star = obj.query_star; //actualiza tiempo de ejecucion

                            }
```

Comment: Por favor: procura compartir tu código como texto, mostrar la estructura de la tabla como texto e incluir datos de prueba como texto. Así será más fácil hacer pruebas y sugerir soluciones. Gracias!

Comment: [Te podrían votar negativamente porque una captura del código no es de ayuda](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2869/21). Edita tu pregunta y deja el texto del código. Un saludo.

Comment: Podrias poner el codigo como texto en lugar de una imagen, pero la parte de los parametros, edita la pregunta para agregar ese codigo

Comment: ya edite mi pregunta gracias..

Answer (score 1):

Para evitar el null debes validarlo, no se cual es el campo que causa el problema pero deberias ver en la tabla que columnas permiten `null` y usar

```
obj.usename = dat["usename"] == DBNull.Value ? "" : Convert.ToString(dat["usename"]);
```

usando el `DBNull.Value` puede validar si el valor es null en la columna o no
Use esa columna a modo de ejemplo, lo deberias replicar al resto de las columnas que permiten null

Tambien puedes usar

```
 if(dat["xact_start"] == DBNull.Value){
     obj.Xact_star = Convert.ToDateTime(dat["xact_start"]);
 }
```

Si es que quieres hacerlo en mas de una linea de codigo

Por otro lado observo algunos puntos detalles

- Para que esta el `if (obj == null || obj !=null)` no tiene ningun sentido ese if, deberias quitarlo
- Porque usas `dic.Add(obj.pid, obj);` justo antes de validar `if (!dic.ContainsKey(obj.pid))` lo agregar pero despues validas, eso tampoco tiene sentido

Comment: gracias por responder..El campo que permite el null es un campo dateTime es la siguiente. obj.Xact_star = Convert.ToDateTime(dat["xact_start"]);

Comment: bien bueno agrega la validacion que comente a ese campo, por supuesto la propiedad deberia permitir null o en caso contrario asignar un valor por defecto

Comment: Gracias ya pude solucionar mi error aunque utilice la segunda opcion del if..porque el primero no me dejo asignarle un valor dateTime..Gracias por la ayuda.. saludos..